# How do i round up the value up to 2 decimals in PHP

Tags: php

iam doing division of these two columns $row['col1']/$row['col2'] iam getting value as 
   0.0042553191489362

How do i round up the value so that i can get as 0.42%

Comment: PHP documentation is really easy: php.net/math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) built in function:

```
$myFloat = $row['col1']/$row['col2'];
$result = round($myFloat, 2);
```

Comment: OK...multiply it by 100 then apply round?

Comment: How do i do in Single statement .is there any thing wrong with this statement such as operator precedence 

round($row['col1']/$row['col2']*100,'2')

Comment: Well, the second parameter shouldn't have quotes round it, and to me, the first parameter is ambiguous: does the author mean ($row['col1']/$row['col2'])*100 or $row['col1']/($row['col2']*100) ?